# Spring data mongoDB: Get the distinct fields with pagination

Tags: spring, mongodb, pagination, distinct

I want to implement method for getting distict values with pagination using spring MongoDb.
For exaple here I want to get just 2 distinct userMailBoxAddresses. But in result I received list of all distict values. So pagination does not work

```
        Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(0, 2);
        Query query = new Query().with(pageable);
        Page<String> page;
        List<String> distinct = mongoTemplate.findDistinct(query, "userMailBoxAddress",
            Entity.class, String.class);
```

I found that "The current Distinct() implementation only allows for bringing back ALL distinct values in the collection or matching a query, but there is no way to limit these results. "

Is it true? and maybe is some another way to implement getting distinct values with pagination?

Answer (score 2):

for small collections, this could be an option:

```
Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(0, 2);
GroupOperation groupOp = Aggregation.group("userMailBoxAddress");
SortOperation sortOp = Aggregation.sort(Direction.ASC, "_id");
SkipOperation skipOp = Aggregation.skip(pageable.getPageNumber() * pageable.getPageSize() * 1L);
LimitOperation limitOp = Aggregation.limit(pageable.getPageSize());
        
Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(groupOp, sortOp, skipOp, limitOp);
        
List<String> distinct = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, Entity.class, Document.class)
        .getMappedResults()
        .stream()
        .map(result -> (String)result.get("_id"))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thanks! What if I have 100,000 distinct values?

Comment: [mongodb docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.skip/) say "As the offset increases, skip() will become slower."

Comment: is there some criteria you can `$match` by before the distinct?

Comment: Nope. I will have over 1 million records in the future.. and need to get just distinct userMailBoxAddress fields (around 100,000). 500 records per one page. I am worring about processing time

Comment: there is a `.withOptions(Aggregation.newAggregationOptions().allowDiskUse(true)` that you can try to add to the end of the `newAggregation` line for the [mongodb allowDiskUse](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.allowDiskUse/)
I think it will be slow using `skip`.

Comment: How about creating a separate collection with just the distinct values as the `_id`? If the is a `_id` key for each record, there are other options that can be used instead of `$skip`.  see https://medium.com/swlh/mongodb-pagination-fast-consistent-ece2a97070f3

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking about separate collection as well.  But right now its not a case for me I think. Do I need use sorting? Can aggregate reusult return different data for pages. E.g. without sorting i get first page with distinct 500 records. After make a new  mongoTemplate.aggregate call for next page (skip=500, limit=500) is it possible that records will be grouped in another way and we will receive same records or miss some of them?

Comment: If I will not use pagination and make a call  to get distict fields: ```List<String> distinctMailBoxAddresses = mongoTemplate.findDistinct("userMailBoxAddress", Entity.class, String.class)``` Is it case to do this with 100,000 distict records (e.g. "lalalalalallala@123456.com). Can  that call use excessive amount of RAM or, during transmission, excessive amount of bandwidth?

Comment: Its worth a try to see at what limit it will break. I have seen aggregations break without `allowDiskUse` with large data